# Amazon MQ Consumer unable to fetch data

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, amazon-mq

I have created a simple consumer for `Amazon MQ` but looks like i missed something because whenever a message came it should call my recevieMessage method but its not working.
But I tried this with apache active MQ its working perfectly.

PS: I also tried with implementing `MessageListener` class overrides the `onMessage()` method but not working.
I tried with different arguments in  `receiveMessage` method like `Object`, `Message`, `ByteMessage`....

```
public class Receiver {
    @JmsListener(destination = "Queue_Name")
    public void receiveMessage(final  Message consumerMessage) throws JMSException {
    --some logic on data 
    }
}
```

My Configuration:

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableJms//enable jms
    public class ReceiverConfig {
    @Bean//created a ActiveMQ Connection Factory 
      public ActiveMQConnectionFactory receiverActiveMQConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory =
            new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setUserName(userName);
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setPassword(passWord);
        return activeMQConnectionFactory;
      }

      @Bean// Uses default Jms Listener Container Factory
      public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
            new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory
            .setConnectionFactory(receiverActiveMQConnectionFactory());

        return factory;
      }

      @Bean
      public Receiver receiver() {
        return new Receiver();
      }
}
```

Geeting this every time i start the application: 
`WARN 12740 --- [206:61616@63304] o.a.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor     : Received a message on a connection which is not yet started. Have you forgotten to call Connection.start()? Connection: ActiveMQConnection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I foget to mention my user defined jms lisner connection factory name to `@jmsListner` annotation.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "Queue-name",containerFactory ="jmsListenerContainerFactory" )
    public void receiveMessage(@Payload final  Message consumerMessage) throws JMSException {
        LOGGER.info("Into receiveMessage Method");
}
```

But I am still unable to find how this is working for any other activeMQ.